# Will disabling "Automatically download updates if my data settings allow it" blocks automatic updates when connected to Wi-Fi?

Tags: update

My Wi-Fi isn't unlimited and I need to block any automatic updates. In phone update screen, there is an option "Automatically download updates if my data settings allow it". Unchecking the option prevents download through mobile data, but what about automatic downloads through Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't over the WiFi. But it does on the data connection.

Although if you are talking about app updates you can disable automatic updates from Store's settings and manually update apps when you are on unlimited data.

Automatic OS updates can't be prevented on WiFi at the moment.

Comment: Is it possible to block OS updates from Store settings?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: But, Windows updates are from Windows store? Why going to Windows Store settings?

Comment: Store settings are for apps! which I already mentioned in my answer. There's no way currently to prevent automatic OS updates when you are on WiFi

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings >> Background Apps >> Phone Update

Turn Off Phone Update

Comment: Is there something like this Windows Phone? I've never seen it. Which phone are you talking about?

Comment: When you have updated your phone to windows 10 anniversary update, you can use this feature.

Comment: Great feature. But it is not accessible to Windows 8.1 users who cannot upgrade to Windows 10. Also, it is not good to upgrade to the latest version just to block updates. Windows 8.1 users should upgrade to Windows 10 and then to Windows 10 anniversary update. Microsoft should make the updates smaller in size, or implement separate features as different updates, or something like an app for different feature might help.

Comment: Thanks Ramakrishnan for the great help, and for letting me know about this feature in Windows 10 Anniversary update. I think it's time to upgrade to Windows 10 and anniversary update. I am on Lumia 540 with Win 8.1 Denim. Going to upgrade too soon